# Algorithms better than meet-in-the-middle

Tags: algorithm, math, finite-field

I am given `n = 256` 64-bit binary vectors ∈ [GF(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GF(2))^64. I am also given a `k` and a target vector `T`, and I am required to choose exactly `k` out of the `n` vectors without repetition such that their sum (mod 2) is T. Such a solution is guaranteed to exist.

Obviously, a meet-in-the-middle attack would give a solution in approximately O(n^(k / 2)). However, I am wondering if the there exists faster solutions when `k` is really small compared to the number of dimension 64, say for k = 16. The reason I think so is that 16 vectors can only span a 16-dimensional space and so the existence of such solution is a strong information.

I have also thought of reducing the `n` to 64, since we can always choose 64 vectors that span GF(2)^64. However, I believe that would violate the "exactly `k`" part of the requirement. Or am I missing something obvious here?

Thank you for reading, any discussion would be helpful.

Comment: It's a hard problem: https://madhu.seas.harvard.edu/papers/1999/dms-journ.pdf

Comment: Unrelated to the dimension but if k is small enough then a simple enumeration of all n choose k choices of k vectors will be faster than meet-in-the-middle. For your example of (n,k)=(256,16), 256 choose 16 is about 2^84, much less than 2^128.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Won't a meet in the middle attack be 256^(k/2) = 256^8 = 2^64 instead? Thank you for your answer anyways.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I believe two years ago I didn't understand any of that paper, but since then, I have learned some (code-based) cryptography. Thanks for the reference :)

Answer (score 0):

We're given `n` binary vectors `v_i` in F_2^d and a target vector `T`, and we want a `k`-subset of `{v_i}` that sums to `T`.

The natural thing to do first is to pack the vectors into a matrix, so we form `M = [v1 | v2 | ... | vn]`. The problem becomes finding a binary vector `w` with hamming weight `k` such that `wM = T`.

This can be solved using ISD (Information-Set Decoding). First find any `w0` by linear algebra. Then we want to find a low weight vector in `w0 + kerL(M)`, where `kerL` means left kernel. This can be done by decoding `-w0` in the code `kerL(M)`.